# How do I vertically align elements inside a centered column, using Bulma?

Tags: css, bulma

**How do I vertically align elements inside a centered column using Bulma?**

current results:
[image]

My code:

```html
<template>
  <div id="dataFetcher" class="box">
    <h1 class="block">Data Fetcher</h1>
    <div class="columns is-vcentered is-centered">
      <div id="123" class="column has-background-success is-half">
          <input type="text" class="">
          <button type="button" :class="{ 'is-loading': isLoading } " class="block button is-vcentered" @click="fetchData">Fetch data</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Thinking:

I've used a `.columns .is-centered` div to center horizontally. Check.

But for vertical alignment, `.columns .is-vcentered` isn't the answer because it requires two separate columns (which feels like the wrong approach to me?).

Other references I've seen imply using `.is-flex .is-align-items-center` to get some Flexbox action going, but putting that on or inside the column div breaks the horizontal alignment from `.columns`.

Answer (score 0):

It helps if the text input has a class of `input`, then I would put the fields into a horizontal field container:

```
<template>
  <div id="dataFetcher" class="box">
    <h1 class="block">Data Fetcher</h1>
    <div class="columns is-vcentered is-centered">
      <div id="123" class="column has-background-success is-narrow">

        <div class="field is-horizontal">
          <div class="field-body">
            <div class="field">
              <p class="control">
                <input type="text" class="input">
              </p>
            </div>
            <div class="field">
              <p class="control">
                <button type="button" class="button">Fetch data</button>
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```